# Pointer arithmetic and 2-D array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to C and got stuck on "How to pass multidimensional array to a function". I do understand that you have to pass column size so that if you want to go from `a[0][0]` to `a[1][0]` it can calculate the size of 1-D array and can jump over it.

I have written a small program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void foo(char[][2]);
int main()
{
     char arr[2][2] = {'a','b','c','d'};

     foo(arr);
     return 0;
}

void foo(char temp[][2])
{
      temp++;
      printf("%c",*temp);
}
```

I expected that this code will print the letter `c`, since `temp` initially points to `'a'` and once we increment it, it will skip over first 1-d array and go to first element of second 1-d array which is `'c'`. But it does not work that way I guess.

Please explain the how compiler computes these addresses.

Comment: Didn't you get a warning when compiling that code? If not, use `-Wall`. Don't ignore warnings.

Comment: @CoolGuy - The only error OP original will get is non-fatal run-time due to parameter mismatch, and a subsequent -1 return error from printf.  I have my compiler set to aggressive, and get no warnings or errors.

Comment: @ryyker I get `warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]` and `warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]`. Are you sure you get no warnings?

Comment: @CoolGuy - Yes, I am sure.  I have set my compiler to both C89 and C99, both times set to aggressive.  No warnings or errors at compile time. However, from looking at comments under Olaf's post, I see he also gets warnings.  He is using GCC.  What are you using?

Comment: @ryyker I'm using GCC too. [Here is a demo](http://rextester.com/OIYW33922) where you can see the warnings emitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For function argument `char temp[][2]`, `temp` decays to a pointer. But only for the first (outer) dimension. So it is effectively a *pointer to array `[2]` of `char`*.

Incrementing the pointer will advance it to the next **outer** index, as you already assumed.

So, you either have to use `(*temp)[0]` or `**temp` to get the first element. `**temp` works, because `*temp` is an array itself, so it decays to a pointer to the first element of the inner array. The second (left) `*` then dereferences this pointer: `c`.

Note that, allthough it uses the same syntax like `char **temp`, they are fundamentally different. A pointer is not an array and here, incrementing `temp` will only advance by the size of a pointer, which is not what you want.

Note that the initializer would better be according to the 2-simensional nature:

```
{ { 'a', 'b' } , { 'c', 'd' } }
```

This ensures you get the correct values for the inner arrays and is good practice. Omitting a value in the non-nested form will result in wrong sequence for the inner array. When having enabled the recommended warnings (`-Wall`) **at least**, gcc warns about missing braces.

Comment: Out of curiosity, for what compiler settings are you able to get a compiler error (or even a warning) for the initializer OP used?  It appears to be completely legal and sufficient.  By adding the curly braces, you've improved readability, but nothing else.

Comment: @ryyker: Just the standard warnings enabled: `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -O3 test.c`
`test.c: In function ‘main’:` `test.c:19:2: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]`

Comment: Hmm.  must be a gcc extension thing.  The C standard does not require the inner braces.

Comment: @ryyker: Huh? This is an array of array, so they are actually fully compliant - they are [**not** an extension](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p26). Hmm, actually you seem to have a point, reading on in the linked paragraph, the original versions seems to be correct, too. However, that looks like another legacy to me.

Comment: My internet is spotty where I am right now.  Sorry for delay.  It would have been more correct for me to say that inner braces, although not required, remove ambiguity to initialization by adding specificity to where each initializer will be placed in memory (or in the array).  Your edit is good.

Answer (score 6):

The pointer arithmetic is good. You just forgot to dereference `*temp`, which has type `char[2]`.

Change it to `**temp`, and you'll get an output `c`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply it worked. but could you please explain how compiler computes the address of a 2-D array or given me some link where i can find explanation .

Answer (score 3):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

In `main`, the type of the expression `arr` in the function call `foo(arr)` is "2-element array of 2-element array of `char`"; since it isn't the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it "decays" to an expression of type "pointer to 2-element array of `char`", or `char (*)[2]`.

Thus, the parameter `temp` is type `char (*)[2]`, and it points to the first element of `arr`.  The parameter declaration `char temp[][2]` is equivalent to `char (*temp)[2]`.  The expression `*temp` is equivalent to `temp[0]`, and both have type "2-element array of `char`" (`char [2]`).  The expression `temp + 1` gives you the address of the next 2-element array of `char`, so `*(temp + 1)` is equivalent to `temp[1]`.

Here's a table to summarize all of that:

```
    Expression        Type            Decays To         Value
    ----------        ----            ---------         -----
           arr        char [2][2]     char (*)[2]       &arr[0][0]
          *arr        char [2]        char *            arr[0]
          &arr        char (*)[2][2]  n/a               &arr[0][0]
        arr[i]        char [2]        char *            &arr[i][0]
       *arr[i]        char            n/a               arr[i][0]
       &arr[i]        char (*)[2]     n/a               &arr[i][0]
     arr[i][j]        char            n/a               arr[i][j]

          temp        char (*)[2]     n/a               &arr[0][0]
         *temp        char [2]        char *            arr[0]
         &temp        char (**)[2]    n/a               addr of temp variable
       temp[i]        char [2]        char *            &arr[i][0]
      *temp[i]        char            n/a               arr[i][0]
      &temp[i]        char (*)[2]     n/a               &arr[i][0]
    temp[i][j]        char            n/a               arr[i][j]

       arr + 1        char [2][2]     char (*)[2]       &arr[1][0]
    *(arr + 1)        char [2]        char *            arr[1]
      temp + 1        char (*)[2]     n/a               &arr[1][0]
   *(temp + 1)        char [2]        char *            arr[1]

     arr[0][0]        char            n/a               'a'
     arr[0][1]        char            n/a               'b'
     arr[1][0]        char            n/a               'c'
     arr[1][1]        char            n/a               'd'

        **temp        char            n/a               'a'
      *temp[0]        char            n/a               'a'
    temp[0][0]        char            n/a               'a'

  **(temp + 1)        char            n/a               'c'
      *temp[1]        char            n/a               'c'
    temp[1][0]        char            n/a               'c'
```

So, in your print statement, you would write either

```
printf("%c", **temp); // temp == &arr[1][0] after temp++
```

or

```
printf("%c", *temp[0]); // temp[0] == arr[1] after temp++
```

or

```
printf("%c", temp[0][0]); // temp[0][0] == arr[1][0] after temp++
```

The expressions `arr`, `&arr`, `*arr`, `arr[0]`, `&arr[0]`, `*arr[0]`, and `&arr[0][0]` all yield the same *value* - the address of the first element of `arr` (remember that the address of the array and the address of the first element of the array are the same). They just differ in type.

Note that `&temp` gives us a *different* value than `&arr`.  Since temp was declared as a pointer, not an array, `&temp` gives us the address of the pointer variable.

A picture may help:

```
      +---+    
 arr: |'a'|  arr[0][0] <------------------+ before temp++
      +---+                               |
      |'b'|  arr[0][1]                    |
      +---+                               |
      |'c'|  arr[1][0] <--+ after temp++  |   
      +---+               |               |
      |'d'|  arr[1][1]    |               |
      +---+               |               |
       ...                |               |
      +---+               |               |
temp: |   |---------------+---------------+
      +---+
```

Comment: Thanks for the nicely explained answer.

Comment: The table is awesome.